# Spock testing - assign value from when clause to local variable

Tags: spring, groovy, integration-testing, spock

I write integration test for protected resources and therefore I have to log in, get the token from request and in the next test use this token.

I wanted to do it like below:

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate

private String token

def 'login'() {
        given:
            final UserData userData = new UserData("User", "Password")

        when:
            def response = restTemplate.postForEntity('/login', userData, Object)
// assign token to variable
            this.token = response.getHeaders().get("Authorization")

        then:
            response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK
            response.getHeaders().get("Authorization") != null
    }
```

And I wanted to use assigned token in the next test, but I get NUllPointerException:

```
def 'request test'() {

    final MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>()
    headers.add("Authorization", token)
    final HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers)

when:
    def response = rest.exchange('/test', HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {})

then:
    response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK
```

}

In this test token has null value. Why and how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on tests running in order, or share state between them.  Why not extract those 3 lines into a method, and call that in each test to get a token?

Answer (score 1):

Normal fields are not shared between test executions, if you want to share them you need to annotate the field with `@spock.lang.Shared`. If you want to execute your tests in a deterministic order, then you need to annotate your spec with `@spock.lang.Stepwise`.

```
@Stepwise
class Test {

  @Shared
  String token

  def test1() {/* ... */ }
  def test2() {/* ... */ }
}
```